# Side-channel pass-through combinator for haskell conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

Is there any combinator:

```
ConduitT i o m r -> CondiutT i ([i], o) m r
```

That passes through the inputs to be consumed downstream?

If not, is there any way to create this in a clean way using the combinators available in the core package?

The "actual problem" I have -- I am composing/mapping these with a "test" function to test the original `ConduitT i o m r`, to check that each resulting `o` makes sense with the `i`s that it saw.  I'd be either mapping a `([i],o) -> Bool` function, or composing it with some `ConduitT ([i], o) Bool m r` which outputs a `Bool` for every `([i], o)` received, with some potential monadic effects.  It might be that there is a better way to do all of this!  One way I have thought of is to use a Chan/TChan if m is IO, but I might not necessarily be doing this in IO.

I've tried simply composing/mapping the `o` results of the `ConduitT i o`, but I don't have any access to the `i`s that it consumed, so I'm a bit stuck; this pass-through operator is one what I thought of that might help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a conduit expert, but your mention of `Chan` makes me wonder what you think of the alternate type signature `ConduitT i o m r -> ConduitT i ([i], o) (StateT [i] m) r`. Might be easier to implement.

Comment: What should happen when no `o` is produced for an `i`, or when multiple `o`s are produced for an `i`?

Comment: @danidiaz If `i`s are 'skipped' then they could probably arbitrarily show up in the output list of the next `o` that does pop out.  "multiple `o`s are produced for an `i`" would probably arbitrarily associate the single `i` with the first `o` that saw it, and the others would be passed along with empty lists.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the tip!  That ended up working actually!  I added an `iterM (\x -> modify (x:))` to the chain after the `i` producer, and then can `state (,[])` to flush and grab all of the items in the part where I test the `o`s.  This will probably work for now, unless there is a more "native" way that comes up here :)

Comment: @JustinL. You should write up a few details in the "Your Answer" box below! (Don't worry; though it may seem a bit weird, answering your own question is considered exemplary behavior on StackOverflow.)